# cron not running in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, cron, python

I have created `downloads` file inside `/etc/cron.d/` directory.

Following is the content of the `downloads` file.

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /path/python.py
```

File permissions and owner:

-rw-r--r--   1 root root   79 Dec 25 22:45 downloads

```
systemctl status crond
```

Above command gave the following error.

```
Unit crond.service could not be found.
```

`/usr/bin/python3 /path/python.py` this executes correctly from terminal.

Comment: (perhaps `systemctl status crond` instead?).  Can you confirm that `/usr/bin/python3 /path/python.py` executes correctly when run as root, outside of cron?

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes. it is showing Active: active (running)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes. it executes correctly.

Comment: @AkshayRathod these updates would be better [as an edit to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/559974/edit) so that no one else wonders the same thing. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller `systemctl status crond` gave this error `Unit crond.service could not be found.`

Comment: Are there relevant cron logs in /var/log/syslog, or from `sudo journalctl -t CROND`?

Comment: @Quasímodo `cat /etc/cron.d/downloads | wc -l` this command gave `0` as output.

Comment: The unit name is `cron` **not** `crond`: `systemctl status cron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append one blank line to the end of your `downloads` file. Cron jobs need new line termination characters.

Also, it is better to manage cron jobs with `crontab -e` (if you want root priviledges, `sudo crontab -e`). In case you forget the new line, crontab will warn you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much @quasimodo :)